# Object mapping in laravel post form

Tags: php, laravel

Hello I'm not sure how to correctly ask, but the problem I face is to serialize form body in to objects:

I have form:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('action') }}">
  <table>
    @foreach($items as $item)
     <td>
       <input name="name[]" value={{ $item->price }}>
     </td>
     <td>
       <input name="price[]" value={{ $item->name }}>
     </td>
    @endforeach
  <table>
</form>
```

With send me data:

```
[
    "name" =>  [
        0 => "camera",
        1 => "toy"
    ],
    "price" =>  [
        0 => "120",
        1 => "120"
    ]
]
```

Is there a proper way to create from this fields a proper objects or arrays like this:

```
[ "name" => "camera", "price" => "120" ],
[ "name" => "120", "price" => "120" ]
```

I know I can use loops... But is there a laravel way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rebuild your form as, note `name` attributes:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('action') }}">
  <table>
     <!-- btw, where's tr tag? -->
     <td>
       <input name="items[0][name]" value={{ $item->price }}>
     </td>
     <td>
       <input name="items[0][price]" value={{ $item->name }}>
     </td>
     <td>
       <input name="items[1][name]" value={{ $item->price }}>
     </td>
     <td>
       <input name="items[1][price]" value={{ $item->name }}>
     </td>
     <!-- etc -->
  <table>
</form>
```

With such naming you will have `$_POST['items']` with subarrays of required structure.

Note **explicit** indexes in `name` attributes. Naming like `item[][name]` will **not work**.

Comment: Sorry for tr, i was writing an example here on stack

Answer (score 1):

Before rendering template you can process your data using [**array_combine ( array $keys , array $values ) : array**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php)

```
$items = [
    "name" =>  [
        0 => "camera",
        1 => "toy"
    ],
    "price" =>  [
        0 => "120",
        1 => "120"
    ]
];

$items = array_combine($data['name'], $data['price']);
```

After rendering, in template using `foreach()` you can populate your proceed data in the table

```
<table>
    @foreach($items as $name => $price)
        <tr>
        <td>
           <input name="name[]" value={{ $name }}>
        </td>
        <td>
           <input name="price[]" value={{ $price }}>
        </td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
<table>
```